# Is Luncheon capitalized when referring to an event?

Tags: orthography

For example: the Intercultural Union "luncheon"

Comment: If "luncheon" is part of the name of an event, then yes.  If it's simply a meal organised by the Intercultural Union, then no.

Comment: I agree with Simon B. See: The Boardman - Volumes 27-28 - Page 70
1972 The Luncheon event drew nearly 200 homefolks last year in far away Anahiem, California, and is expected to attract over 250 this year in Houston, as convention- goers get together briefly to see who's there from home.

Answer (score 1):

Simon B. is correct.

additional comment:
No. But if the luncheon is in honor of a person, for a charity event, or a retirement party the name of the honoree together with the event or occasion's name is capitalized.

Examples:

Charlie Brown's Retirement luncheon.
but,
Healthy Octogenarian Club's Annual Fundraising Luncheon.

Answer (score 1):

If it is part of the name or title of a specific event, then yes. Otherwise no.

> We are having a luncheon for the tenth anniversary of the founding of this college.

Not capitalized, not the name of the event.

> The Foobar University Tenth Anniversary Luncheon will be held on Thursday at noon.

The name of the event is "Foobar University Tenth Anniversary Luncheon", so it is capitalized.